# MacVim Replace All not working properly

Tags: macos, macvim

I have an html file that I need to replace some characters with html entities.  Right now I'm trying to replace **—** with **&mdash;** but when I use the *Replace All* button, the result is that all of those instances of **—** are replaced with **—mdash;**

The strange thing is that if I go to each, one by one, i.e., click *Next*, then click *Replace*, and so on, then it replaces it correctly.

Does the *Replace All* button treat the & character as a wild character? Or is this a bug in MacVim?